# Javascript Average sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

Working on a form with two input fields for a user to input the names and marks of their students, along with four buttons, one adds the name & mark which stores each value in the console. The second displays the stored results in a display box, the third button is a clear all which clears the console and the display box.

The fourth button is to calculate the average of the inputted marks. My problem is that these marks are not stored in the array below, they are stored in the console from the users input. I am trying to take these values stored in the console and work out the average.

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <h4>Enter student results</h4>

    Name:
    <input type="text" id="name" autofocus required>

    Mark:
    <input type="number" id="mark" min="0" max="100" required>




    <div id="buttonBlock">
        <input type="button" id="Add" value="Add Result">
        <input type="button" id="Clear" value="Clear All">
        <input type="button" id="Display" value="Display All">
        <input type="button" id="Average" value="Calculate Average">
    </div>


</form>

<p id="result"></p>
```

```js
let insertName = [];
let insertMark = [];
 //Arrays//

function getTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < mark.length; i++) {
    total += mark.length[i];
  }

  if (mark[i] !== undefined) {
    //legit value//
    count++;
    total += mark[i];
  }

  let avg = total / count;
  console.log(avg)

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " The Average is " + total;
}

document.getElementById("Average").addEventListener("click", getTotal);
```

Comment: `NaN` stands for not a number. Have you set any breakpoints in your code to check what values you have?

Comment: What is `mark`? You have two `i` variables.

Comment: Where does `mark` come from and what is `mark.length[i]` supposed to be?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: mark is an array, but holds no numbers. I am trying to grab the values from the console to work out the average.

Comment: Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and paste HTML and JS into the corresponding panes with an example of the `mark`

Comment: Also the mark variable is empty as the person can type any number in and it stores it

Comment: can you provide exmpleof the `mark` array?

Comment: @Ross If the numbers are text, you need to use `parseInt` to do your addition - (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), also as others have pointed out, you have variable `i` declared twice and your iteration should not have .length on the end of mark but just `mark[i]`. You'll need to do `parseInt(mark[i]);` to do your sum.

Comment: or `mark="1,2,3,4".split\`,\`.map(x=>+x)`

Answer (score 2):

Can't see source of mark to see if they are actually numbers.  You may need to parse to integer.
Didn't notice your intention.  @Niels saw it.

```js
mark = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

function getTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  let count = 0;
  //let i = 0;  // someone edited this to fix poor style

  for (let i = 0; i < mark.length; i++) 
    if (mark[i] !== undefined) {
      //legit value//
      count++;
      total += mark[i];
    }

  let avg = total / count;
  console.log(avg)

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " The Average is " + total;
}

document.getElementById("Average").addEventListener("click", getTotal);
```

```html
<button id="Average">Average</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Created a fully working demo.  But honestly for a small hack like this with a few typos, all he really needed was to have it quickly pointed out where he made mistakes.

Comment: Still not solved, you have to remove the //legit value part aswell. This creates an invalid sum.

Comment: But it is not a _real_ solution. In the check `if (mark[i] !== undefined) {` the value of `i` is `mark.length`. So count is probably 0, and the average calculation is meaningless. I don't remember if division by 0 leads to NaN; if yes that's probably the real issue.

Comment: Uh, why not?  He obviously has code elsewhere that is the source of the HTML element and the mark array.  And now apparently he's saying that he sets the mark array manually through the console.

Comment: let mark = [ ] & let name [ ] are arrays i have created to hold student records. Only they do not hold any names / marks in the code as I am trying to get this to work through user input, so when the user inputs a name and mark for a student I have got the console to store it. Now I am just trying to work out how to grab the values the user has inputted from the console to work out the average of the mark array. Sorry if i'm not providing enough detail, pretty new here

Comment: Oh... in that case these guys might have a point.  Sounds like you needed a little bit more guidance, and were probably better off being lead to hacking out some more stuff out on your own.

Comment: Is there anyway I could use the code I have in the getTotal function to grab the values stored in the console to work out the average ?

Comment: `function getTotal(parameter1, parameter2) {  //do something
return parameter1 + parameter2
}`
then call it from the console

Comment: Ah, put that stuff that you want clearly into your question.  Probs someone will give you a full write up on how you should be writing your code.

Comment: @Ross if you just need to test the values stored in console, you can just copy and paste user120242's code to your browser console, and modify mark array.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys! I appreciate the input

Answer (score 2):

You declared i twice

```
let i = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < mark.length; i++)
```

This code never executed, since your mark.length is 0

```
total += mark[i];
```

And this code is also not executed, because mark[0] is undefined

```
count++;
total += mark[i];
```

Tge avg = 0/0 which is NaN, but total is still 0

Comment: Probably for assuming `mark` does not exist when the code runs

Comment: @mplungjan if you read OP's comment "mark is an array, but holds no numbers."

Comment: `I am trying to grab the values from the console to work out the average. `

Comment: @mplungjan trying to grab the values has nothing to do with empty array. OP already said the array is empty. If array is not empty, then total will be NaN.

Comment: You asked why you might have been voted down I offered a possibility. There are several other issues in OPs code. Yours are not one if mark is filled when clicking the button